# Is this a correct json format

Tags: php, json

I want to get a fair idea about json format... I am using php in which i have converted my result array to json like this

```
$result = mysql_query("select dStud_id,dMarkObtained1,dMarkObtained2,
                dMarkObtained3,dMarkTotal from tbl_internalmarkallot");
$JsonVar = json_encode($res);

echo "<input type='text' name='json' id='json' value ='$JsonVar'>";
```

And the text box shows

`{"0":"101","dStud_id":"101","1":"60","dMarkObtained1":"60","2":"80",
"dMarkObtained2":"80","3":"80","dMarkObtained3":"80","4":"220","dMarkTotal":"220"}`

Is this a correct json format....

Comment: Do you have some reason to suspect that a built in feature of PHP (json_encode), used by vast numbers of people and applications, is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular string is valid JSON. However:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='json' id='json' value ='$JsonVar'>";
```

is missing a call to `htmlspecialchars`, so if there happens to be a single quote in one of your values, you've got a broken attribute, resulting in invalid JSON and HTML-injection, leading to potential XSS security holes.

Remember to HTML-escape **every** text string you output into HTML, eg.:

```
<input type="text" name="json" id="json" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($JsonVar); ?>">
```

or, you can use the PHP 5.3 `JSON_HEX` options to ensure HTML-special characters are not present, avoiding the need for this step:

```
<?php $jsonVar= json_encode($res, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_AMP); ?>
<input type="text" name="json" id="json" value="<?php echo $jsonVar; ?>">
```

Answer (score 7):

There is an online [JSON validator](http://www.jsonlint.com/) and it sais that it is valid JSON. If you use JSON more often I would recommend the [JSON View](http://benhollis.net/software/jsonview/) firefox plugin.

Comment: Awesome plugin! I got into a nasty habit of turning off the application/json header when debugging, this is much better.

Answer (score 0):

The json parser on http://json.parser.online.fr/ says this is valid json.

Answer (score -1):

it's correct but you're better off using something like this:

```
<?php
  $myResultArray = array();
  $result = mysql_query("select dStud_id,dMarkObtained1,dMarkObtained2, dMarkObtained3,dMarkTotal from tbl_internalmarkallot");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    static $i = 0;
    $myResultArray[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
  }

  $JsonVar = json_encode($myResultArray);

  echo '<input type="text" name="json" id="json" value="'.$JsonVar.'">';
?>
```